# jQuery replaceWith and toggle conflict

Tags: jquery, toggle, conflict, replacewith

I have the html

```
<div id=1>
  <span id=2></span>
</div>
<div id=3>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace `span` with `a` and use the anchor to `.toggle()` `<div id=3>`

```
$('#2').replaceWith(function(){
  return $("<a id=\"2\" href=\"#\" />").append($(this).contents());
});
```

This works at turning the span to an anchor, but when I try to chain a click function `.toggle()`, it refuses to toggle.

```
$('#2').replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<a id=\"2\" href=\"#\" />").append($(this).contents());
}).click(function() {
  $('#3').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

The click function `.toggle()` works if I remove `.replaceWith()`.

Comment: toggle is becoming deprecated anyway :(

Comment: Then what's the alternative?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think the toggle event is.. not the toggle effect

Comment: I found a solution, unless someone has a more clean way of doing this.

`$('#2').parent()each(function() {
var html = $(this).html();
html = html.replace('span','a');
$(this).html(html);
});`

Comment: @gavsiu Great! then you should answer it yourself and accept your answer when you are able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution

```
$('#2').replaceWith(function(){
  return $('<a id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '" href="#" />').append($(this).contents());
});

$('#2').click(function() {
  $('#3').toggle();
  scrollToDiv($(this),0);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the element you just removed.

```
$('#2') // <-- here you already selected the span
// now you replaced it with a new element
.replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<a id=\"2\" href=\"#\" />").append($(this).contents());
})
// the selector is still on the span so you bound the click event to the span
.click(function() {
  $('#3').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

What you can do is use delegation so it doesn't matter what changes you make to the element.  Bind it to a parent element

```
$('#1').on('click','#2',function(){
      //your code here
});
```

Now your parent element will listen to the click events that bubble up and handle them.. So it doesn't matter how many times you change the #2 element - as long as it's id=2 then it will trigger the handler

Comment: In my actual code, #1 is actually does not have an ID, just a common class. Will `$('#2').parent();` work?

Comment: You can use any parent element.. one that you can select.. or if not you can always opt to use 'body'

Comment: I think you're right, but I found that if I don't chain the click function with the replaceWith, it works. Just select #2 again.

Comment: @gavsiu yeah that will work too.. It's because you select the the element and bound it to the correct one where chaining will bind to the element that was removed.  Delegation makes it so dynamic changes to the dom will not affect it because the event handler is attached to the parent.. so it doesn't how many times you change #2 - when the event bubbles up the parent element will handle the event